# Elements disappear vue js template in safari

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I wonder if anyone has experienced this before.

I have a vue 2 template rendering using vuetify 2, it has some buttons on the page to navigate between sub pages. But in safari **only**, those buttons "flash" on the page load and then disappear?

I can inspect them and see them in the DOM, im finding that removing some inline style properties (overflow: auto etc) can hack it back to showing.

But any other browser on any other platform theyve all been working perfectly fine. I also have another vue template which has similar buttons setup and that also works in safari.

The other factor ive found as well is that stretching the browser window to a stupidly wide width renders the button?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing a parent element from position: absolute to position: fixed, i hope that helps someone, it destroyed me for a few hours :-) happy coding